# freetype when FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face,FONDSIZE,FONDSIZE) face->glyph->bitmap.rows>FONDSIZE

Tags: c, fonts, font-size, freetype

I want to create font image. But when I use:

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face,FONDSIZE,FONDSIZE)
```

and render

```
FT_Render_Glyph(..,FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL)
```

I found bitmap.rows may be greater than FONDSIZE (test in 24/32 msyh.ttf).

How can I determine the maximum size for allocate memory?